# ColdFusion - Regex to match SRC with single quotes

Tags: regex, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, railo

I have a simple regex line to extract the src="" value from an image tag:

```
<cfset variables.attrSrc = REMatch("(?i)src\s*=\s*""[^""]+", variables.myImageTag) />

<!--- REMatch("(?i)src\s*=\s*""[^""]+" --->
```

However, while this works great, it doesn't appear to be working with src='' attrubutes that display single quotes instead of double.

Ideally, I'd like it to work with both single quotes and double.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,
Michael.

Comment: Where does the image tag string come from? i.e. What happens if you have `src=filename.png` or `altsrc="..."` or `data-src="..."`? If you're not in full control of the input, you should use a HTML parser (e.g. [jsoup](http://jsoup.org)) to handle this, instead of regex.

Comment: Great idea. I'm on a shared host though - is this something I can install myself or does it require any lower-level access? I'm not versed in Java at all.

Comment: Depends on the shared host and whether they have Java enabled - being on Railo you can place the JAR file in same directory and do `createObject('java','org.jsoup.Jsoup','./jsoup-1.6.3.jar')` - if that works then it's fine to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(?i)src\s*=\s*(""[^""]+""|'[^']+')
```

Comment: That actually causes a syntax error in the context of CFML. Perhaps one too many quotes somewhere?

Comment: I add another double quote to escape one of them that was causing an issue. For anyone wondering, it should be: (?i)src\s*=\s*(""[^""]+""|'[^']+')  ...so in CFML, it is: REMatch("(?i)src\s*=\s*(""[^""]+""|'[^']+')", variables.myImageTag)

Comment: @MichaelGiovanniPumo - Oops, sorry.  Forgot to escape that one.